# How to base 64 encrypt and base 64 decrypt image file in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have one form field called file upload,here i moved one tmp_folder after that i stored in Database,from here working fine,but my requirement is i don't want to move in tmp_folder,i want to encrypt the filename and directly insert the DB,i think i want to use base64 encrypt but i don't know how to use?

```html
<?php
 $userid = $_POST['userid'];// here i got userid
 $filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);//here i got filename
 $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $new_name= md5($filename.time()).'.'.$extension;
 $approved = 0;
 $approved_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $updated_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $status = 0;
 if (!empty($new_name)) {
 // FILE TYPE CHECKING
  $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
 if(!in_array($extension,$allowed) ) {
  $horoscope = array("message" => "filetype error");
  echo json_encode($horoscope);
 }
 else{
 if($_FILES['file']['size']>4459681){
  $horoscope = array("message" => "filesize error");
  echo json_encode($horoscope);
 }
 else{
  //echo "filesize(success)";
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id_proof FROM user_details WHERE user_id='$userid'");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($count != 0){
   $filemove = array("filemove" => move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "horoscope/".$new_name));
   $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE user_details SET id_proof='$new_name',updated_on='$updated_on' WHERE user_id='$userid'");
   if($sql){
   $horoscope = array("message" => "update success");
   }else{
   $horoscope = array("message" => "update error");
   }
   echo json_encode($horoscope);
  }else{
   $filemove = array("filemove" => move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "horoscope/".$new_name));
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_details (user_id,horoscope,approved,approved_on,status) VALUES ('$userid','$new_name','$approved','$approved_on','$status')");
   if($sql){
   $horoscope = array("message" => "successully insert");
   }else{
   $horoscope = array("message" => "insert error");
   }
   echo json_encode($horoscope);
  }
 } 
 } 
}else{
 //echo "Error";
 $horoscope = array("message" => "file is not moving");
 echo json_encode($horoscope);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Base64 ***encoding*** is not *"encryption"*!

Comment: K how can do my requirement?

Comment: I'm unclear what that requirement is exactly. You just want to *save the file into the database*? You don't need base64 for that. Just `file_get_contents` to read the file, put it in your query to save into a BLOB column, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: I want to encode the value after that only ,i want insert the value in DB,

Comment: *Why* encode it? What problem do you have doing so? What problem do you have inserting it into the database?

Comment: User upload id proof ,so i want to write secure code for file upload,so i need help?

Comment: Base64 has nothing to do with "security".

Comment: I want like this, data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA ,,,,  How can do?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $filename = $_FILES['file']['image']
 $destinationPath = 'upload path';
 move_uploaded_file($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

<-----encode----->

```
$im = file_get_contents(file path with filename);
$imdata = base64_encode($im);
```

can store to database image data -> $imdata
<-----/encode----->

<-----decode----->

```
$ifp = fopen($output_file_path_with_filename, "wb");
$$imdata = $base64_string; // $base64_string; from your database. 
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($imdata));
fclose($ifp);
```

<-----/decode----->

Comment: $path = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);//here i am getting file name

Comment: file_get_contents($path);// here i am getting false.so i can't encode the data

Comment: first store file using php
after that give file name with path where u store

Comment: i can't understand Mr Kevin,possible means update your answer

Comment: 1st we have to encode the data after that only we have store the value in DB,

Comment: Sorry Mr Kevin for me don't want to move any folder,directly i want to store the value how can do?